# Реализация функции изменения цветовой схемы сайта

Tags: php, html, css

Здравствуйте!

Появилась задача сделать функцию, с помощью которой можно менять цветовую схему сайта. Т.е. цвет кнопок, лого, местами фона и т.д.

То есть, чисто изменение кода цвета в CSS-стиле. И вот думаю, как это можно реализовать?

---

Пока, как вариант, вижу создать несколько классов, которые будут при рендеринге, в соответствии с конфигурациями, подставляться в HTML-код.

К примеру при настройке:

```
$config["button_color"] = "green";
```

Будет подставляться класс, который стиллизирует кнопку в зеленый:

```
<button class = "bt-green">Submit</button>
```

Но минус в этом способе, что придётся создавать кучу цветовых схем, и реализовывать много CSS-кода.

Возможно, есть какие-либо варианты получше?

Comment: Делаете несколько базовых классов в css, которые с помощью js будете менять для тега `body`. В самом css все остальные настройки предваряете этим классом. Ессно для каждого класса свой набор

Answer (score 1):

css

```
.bodyclass .myclass{
    color: green;
}
.bodyclass2 .myclass{
    color: red;
}
```

html

```
<body class="bodyclass2" id="body">
    <h1 class="myclass">My First CSS Example</h1>
</body>
```

js

```
document.getElementById("body").classList.remove('bodyclass2');
document.getElementById("body").classList.add('bodyclass');
```

**UPD после комментария автора**

Если предполагается изменение схемы администратором на стороне сервера, то, конечно, мало смысла заморачиваться JavaScript'ом

В таком случае имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону чего-то типа [SASS](https://sass-scss.ru/). Создать единый шаблон, выведя в качестве переменных настраиваемые цвета. В админке, после нажатия кнопки "Сохранить", перезаписывать шаблонный файл с измененными переменными, а дальше SASS-процессором генерировать CSS

Comment: на стороне сервера тем не менее контент тоже должен генериться с нужной цветовой схемой, а не только в js меняться. ибо иначе всегда будет загружаться стандартная схема. а потом меняться на нужную, вызывая визуальные нежелательные эффекты переключения. А поскольку сервер так и так будет уметь генерировать нужную схему, то есть ли смысл переключать что-либо через js?

Comment: вы предлагаете переключать класс у `body`, дак откуда там будет на порядок дольше и сложнее вывести на стороне сервера `<body class="themed theme-{$themeName}>` дабы получить какой нибудь `<body class="themed theme-red'>` и все на этом?

Comment: банально за счёт того, что страницу перезагружать не нужно. Перезагрузка страницы это, как минимум: установка соединения, генерация страницы, загрузка контента, сохранение состояния страницы

Comment: надо понимать смысл задачи. Если суть сайта в том, что пользователь будет сидеть и тыкать мышью на смену цветовой схемы то тут вы правы. Если же этот ресурс на котором пользователь единожды за сессию (или вообще в настройках профиля) будет выбирать цвет, то это 1 запрос на несколько тысяч, что не существенно.

Comment: Друзья, не сам пользователь будет выбирать цветовую схему, а администратор сайта. Цветовые схемы созданы для уникализации шаблона, ибо у меня поставлена задача в разработке CMS. 

Спасибо за ответ, о реализации этого в плане JS подумаю.
Но, возможно ли что-либо сделать, чтобы человек сам мог реализовать схему с нужными ему цветами в панели управления? Хм, подумываю сейчас дать возможность человеку создавать собственные классы. Но вот как это импортировать в CSS?

Comment: @Felix дополнил ответ